# Intellij IDE - Change the Functions in the Generate Menu

Tags: intellij-idea

In the last few days, I modified my IntelliJ Settings and installed a few plugins.
Some of these plugins added new functions to the Generate Menu.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmIrr.png)

I'd like to remove some functions and rearrange the rest.
So my question is, where can I configure the functions of the generate menu?

Comment: Currently it's not possible. You may create feature request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: If there is no way to change the functions in the generate menu, how are the plugins adding new ones? ...and wouldn't it be possible to use the same way the plugins are configuring the menu?

Comment: Plugins could add items to menu, but not delete them.